# How to close a prunsrv service propertly in spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, prunsrv

I'm using apache `prunsrv` service to install a `jar` as a windows service.
When the service is shut down, the application crashes.

```
set PR_STARTMETHOD=main
set PR_STOPMETHOD=exit
```

My startup and shutdown class looks as follows:

```
public class TravelportMainApp {
    private static ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ctx = SpringApplication.run(source, args);
        ctx.registerShutdownHook();
    }

    public static void exit(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        if (ctx != null && ctx instanceof AbstractApplicationContext) {
            ((AbstractApplicationContext) ctx).destroy();
        }
        Sysout("EXIT OK.");
    }
}
```

Result: the exit command "EXIT OK" is printed, but then the command line app crashed saying "commons daemon service runner is not working anymore.". What could be wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up as follows:

```
public static void exit(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    SpringApplication.exit(ctx);
    System.exit(0);
}
```